# Zxing Extra - how to?

Tags: android, zxing

I'm using Zxing Android Embedded (https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded) within my app.

To start the intent, I do a js call:

```
@JavascriptInterface
public void scan(String redirectUrl) {
    IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator((Activity)mContext);
    integrator.setOrientationLocked(false);
    integrator.setCaptureActivity(SmallCaptureActivity.class);
    integrator.setBeepEnabled(false);

    if (redirectUrl != null) {
        Log.e("redirectUrl", redirectUrl);
        integrator.createScanIntent().putExtra("redirectUrl", redirectUrl); // this doesn't work
        integrator.addExtra("redirectUrl", redirectUrl); // this doesn't work
    }
    integrator.setPrompt("");
    integrator.initiateScan();
}
```

Within my MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);



    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (bundle != null) {
        for (String key : bundle.keySet()) {
            Object value = bundle.get(key);
            Log.e("Tag", String.format("%s %s (%s)", key,
                    value.toString(), value.getClass().getName()));
        }
    }
}
```

I do not receive any extras in my onActivityResult.
What's the point?

Comment: getIntent() seems to be wrong. Should be something like result.getXXX()

Comment: Unfortunately, result is an IntentResult and does not offer any methods to receive the extra, nor the original intent: https://github.com/zxing/zxing/blob/master/android-integration/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/integration/android/IntentResult.java

Comment: What `extra` do you miss, when using `IntentResult`. What information do you want? If you want to use "native" result, access the `data` variable in your `onActivityResult`

Answer (score 0):

"createScanIntent" returns an Intent on which you can perform putExtra().

Then you have to manually call startActivityForResult(intent) on that intent.
If you call initiateScan() on the integrator, it won't have the Extras you put since they have been set on the Intent returned by the createScanIntent() call and not on the integrator itself.